# Where can I find sample code for a Jquery flickr image gallery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

If you search for jquery image galley you will get lot of links where you can download the sample code.

For this gallery I am not getting example. Can anybody provide the link if he/she has used this gallery before?

http://devkick.com/lab/fsgallery/

**EDIT**

I am looking for exactly similar..

Comment: You're looking for the code this person used on their page? And you can load the page in the browser? And you're still confused?

Comment: Dude.. I want to see the usage terms too. Just copying the code is not enough.

Comment: If they linked to a library, and the library doesn't have a name, and doesn't have terms in the source then I don't know what to tell you, but to me that would be free code. Any library that has a named element (such as jQuery) even when minified will have that named element (see the jQuery min source). Google that named element. If there are no projects with that name, use the source. If they were worried about it, they would put the source in the file. Like the GPL et al require you to do when you publish (make available) a file.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.userfriendlythinking.com/Blog/BlogDetail.asp?p1=7013&p2=101&p7=3001

The above is a plugin for flickr.   Sorry this is similar but not exact to your gallery example.

Comment: Yaa i know but i am looking for exactly similar.. I think they have removed this . http://galleria.aino.se/